# Orientate an element animated with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-plugins, rotation

I am making an animated van dive along a road, there will be areas users can click on and the graphic will move to this position.

Also the van has change its orientation to match the direction.

I can make it from left to right fine, but I am having trouble making the van drive back again. I can do a step at a time but am stuck when jumping several stops.

I have cheated a little and I have an array which stores the positions and angles.

You can look here: http://esdev.co.uk/trimble/tr77_animation/

I'm using [**transit**](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit) to do the rotation. 'Dests' is the array of the positions, it holds an angle, a reverse angle and positions for top and left.

This is what I have to make the van drive.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Animate stops
function drive(dests)
{
    if( direction == 'forward' ) 
    {
        $.each( dests, function(k,v)
        {
            van.animate(
                {
                    left:  journey[v].left- vanwidth/2,
                    top:  journey[v].top- vanheight/2,

                }, anispeed, function(){

                    van.css({ rotate: journey[v].angle });
                }
            );

        });    
    }
    else if( direction == 'reverse' )
    {
        $.each( dests, function(k,v)
        {

            van.css({ rotate: journey[v].rev });

            van.animate(
                {
                    left:  journey[v].left- vanwidth/2,
                    top:  journey[v].top- vanheight/2,

                }, anispeed);

        });
    }

}
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated. Not too worried about an elegant or efficient answer it just needs to work.

Comment: What about `van.css({ rotate: journey[v].angle + 180 })` ? I guess you've tried that, haven't you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue is when the van gets to the end of the road and you click to go back to step 2 etc the van doesn't rotate but if you go back a step at a time then its fine.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. In reverse, I would read the angle from the previous step and add 180 degrees to it. For instance, if you're step 4 and you want to reverse to step 3, the bus direction should be : step3's direction (vertical, heading up) +180°, which gives you vertical, heading down. So the reverse formula would be `van.css({ rotate: journey[v-1].angle + 180 })`, does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, yes I can make the rotation work going backwards one step at a time, however when I go multiple steps the rotation just jumps to the last angle in the array. I think I need some kind a callback on the rotation, I've setting timeOut etc. Driving me mad as its fine going forwards as the van moves then rotates just need to do it in reverse, really don't want to go down the flash route.

Comment: Did you try my solution, reading [v-1] ?

Comment: Yes I did but I keep getting undefined errors, I take it that '[v-1]' is to get the previous array element? apologies still learning js/jQuery. I think I'm starting to get what you mean,   onwards.

Comment: If you know what `journey[v]` is, you sure know what `journey[v-1]` is :)